# Access uitextFields text from a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm trying to get text from a `UItextField` thats in a custom cell. I tried creating a protocol

```
@class customCellClass
@protocol CustomCellDelegate 

-(void)passText:(CustomCell *)customCell withText:(NSString *)text;
@end

...
@interface
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CustomCellDelegate> delegate;
@end


@interface MainCV<CustomCellDelegate>
@end

@implementation MainVC 
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
CustomCell *cell = ... allocation and initialization
cell.delegate = self;
}

-(void)passText:(CustomCell *)customCell withText:(NSString *)text
{

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
CustomCell *cell = [[customCellClass alloc] init];
cell.delegate = self;
}
```

In another method I want to do like this:

```
[self.delegate passText:self withText:self.myTextField.text];
```

But it doesn't let me do the last thing: `[self.delegate passText...`.

Can someone please explain why it didn't work, and help me figure out a working way to get the textFields text.

Comment: It is simple, just do what you like when textFieldDidChange.

Comment: I have multiple textFields. How do I differentiate 1 from the other?

Comment: You should be able to get indexPath from the `customCell`.

Comment: Do you mean like this: `customCellClass *cell = (customCellClass*)textField.superview.superview.superview;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

Then you can access the `textField.text` from cell.

Comment: I'm not using `didSelectRow...`

Comment: did `textfield` embed in the cell?

Comment: Yes, `textField is linked

Comment: so why don't you use `cell.myTextField` to access the value?

Comment: How can I get `cell`? (I need it outside `cellForRow...`

Comment: `CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];` This is section 0 row 0.

Comment: I don't think it's right to create a new cell to access data from it.

Comment: It is not creating a new cell. It is accessing the cell you **had created** in your tableView. They are different.